# can't get values from url

Tags: 7, uri

i sent values with url `http://localhost/mysite/pagename?f1=1&f2[value][year]=2009&f2[value][month]=1`  (i'm sending filters values)
in the directed page i'm trying to get this value by $_GET[] but when i print it nothing show up(i thinks it's null).
here is my code:

```
<?php
$f1= $_GET['f1'];
$year = $_GET['f2']['value']['year'];
$month = $_GET['f2']['value']['month'];
drupal_set_message($f1,true);
drupal_set_message($month,true);
drupal_set_message($month,true);
$view = views_get_view('emp1')
$view->set_exposed_input(array('f1' => $f1,'f2' => array('year' => $year, 'month' =>   $month)),);
$display_id = 'default';
$view->set_display($display_id);
$view->render();
print($view->preview());
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried printing all of $_GET to see what's in it? drupal_set_message(print_r($_GET, true));

Comment: How can i print it to show all values inside it?

Comment: Array ( [q] => node/194)

Comment: why it's return that value? the $f1 return it's value correctly !!! :|

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get your values like this:

```
$year = $_GET['f2']['value']['year'];
$month = $_GET['f2']['value']['month'];
```

Comment: not work i will edit my post with the php code.
the error massage is:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\modules\php\php.module(74) : eval()'d code on line 9

Comment: That's a different problem, you've got a comma at the end of `$view->set_exposed_input(array('f1' => $f1,'f2' => array('year' => $year, 'month' =>   $month)),);` that shouldn't be there, try removing that

Comment: i tried  
$year = $_GET['f2']['value']['year'];
$month = $_GET['f2']['value']['month'];
but it's not work

Comment: If your code is being run when the URL is `http://localhost/mysite/pagename?f1=1&f2[value][year]=2009&f2[value][month]=1` then that should definitely work. I've just tried it on a local installation and I get the expected values

Comment: i will tell you what i'm doing in my site,i have a views with table dispaly, in views template i created a button which it's link send the filters values (http://localhost/mysite/pagename?f1=1&f2[value][year]=2009&f2[value][month]=1) to a page.--------------- in the directed page in body filed i wrote the code above which i want to display the table views for print it by print module,this is my site Adventure :D.